# How to assign the value of object as types in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, typescript-generics

I have the following object

```
export const tokenStatus = {
    active: {
        status: 'ENABLED',
        label: 'Active',
        type: 'success'
    },
    suspended: {
        status: 'DISABLED',
        label: 'Suspended',
        type: 'warning'
    },
    deleted: {
        status: 'DELETED',
        label: 'Deleted',
        type: 'error'
    },
}
```

I would like to assign the types of status'es into another interface.
What I mean is,
I want to have an Interface called `ITokenStatus` whose type is `ENABLED | DISABLED | DELETED`

I achieved it using `typeof tokenStatus[keyof typeof tokenStatus]['status']` But the type of it is just a `string` not `ENABLED | DISABLED | DELETED`

Comment: Declare it `as const` to avoid automatic widening

Comment: I rather think this should be an [`enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)-eration.